# Cannot write data to a (char* buffer) allocated in user space, from a system call

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, system-calls

I am currently trying to call a system call by passing a `char*` buffer as a parameter. However, I am not able to write any data to the `char*` buffer nor read from the `char*` buffer. I tried allocating data to a `char x = 'a'` and then using `copy_to_user` and vice versa using `copy_from_user`, but nothing works out and no values are copied. I have been trying since way too long and not getting headway. Can someone please help me with this issue or point out where I am going wrong.

The system call is:

```
static void generate_Tasklist(char*,int);
static void generate_Tasklist(char *buffer,int size)
{
    printk("\nINSIDE THE FUNCTION\n");
    char x;
    x = 'a';
    int res = access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE,buffer,size);
    printk("The return value of access_ok is %d\n",res);

    int res1 = copy_to_user(buffer,&x,1);
    printk("\nTHE RESULT AFTER copy_to_user IS %d\n",res1);

    int res2 = copy_from_user(x,buffer,1);
    printk("---------%c\n",x);
    printk("\nTHE RESULT AFTER copy_from_user IS %d\n",res2);
}

asmlinkage long sys_syscall(char __user *buffer,int size) {
   printk("\nThis is the system call to list processes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n");
   generate_Tasklist(buffer,size);
   return 0;
}
```

The user space program is :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *bytes = (char *) malloc( sizeof( struct task_info ) * 3 );
    int size = sizeof( struct task_info ) * 3;

    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(bytes + i) = 'x';
    }

    long int output = syscall(__NR_hello,1,bytes,size);
    printf("\nThe value is %c\n",bytes[0]);
    //print(bytes);
    free( (void *) bytes );
    printf ("The listprocess_syscall() returned %ld\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is overwrite the default value of '`x`' in the buffer by '`a`' for the first byte which is not happening. The value returned by `copy_from_user` and `copy_to_user` is `1`. Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: Not knowing what the function does, shouldn't `copy_from_user(x,buffer,1)` be `copy_from_user(&x,buffer,1)`?

Comment: Note: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: I believe @MikeCAT is correct. Also, can you post what messages actually print to give us a better idea of what's going on?

Comment: You also don't need `(void *)` in `free( (void *) bytes );` unless you're using C++, in which case you shouldn't be using `malloc` or `free` at all, ever. Not ever, no.

Comment: please properly indent the code (when asking the question, highlite the code, then click the `{}` button.)

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: there are other considerations beside the user function and the kernel function, like has the kernel been re-compiled with the additional `__NR_hello` entry in the syscall table.  has that entry been set to point to the `generate_Tasklist()` function?  Has the `generate_Tasklist()` function been compiled/linked into the kernel?    BTW: mighty strange function name, especially given what it does.

Comment: the function: `generate_Tasklist()` is `static`  is it in the same file as the function that handles the syscall()`,  if not, then it will be invisible.  the `generate_Tasklist()` function is returned void, I.E. returned nothing, so how can the user function expect to be getting a `long int` returned value?

Comment: you might want to read/understand the information at: `http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html`

Comment: the functions: `copy_from_user()` and `copy_to_user()` return the number of bytes copied, so the returned value of 1 indicates those function worked correctly.  the most likely problem is the parameters

Comment: another possible problem is the call to `syscall()` is passing the call# pluse 3 parameters, but the call to `sys_syscall()` is only getting 2 parameters and the function: `generate_Tasklist()` is only getting 2 parameters.